# Check folder all image and store first first image to array

Tags: php

```
public function set_array($set_value) {
  /*set empty class*/
  $tempclass = new stdClass();

  /*full Image path src*/
  $search_dir = "/domain/img/company/Image1-000000-016";

  /*open dir*/
  $images = glob("$search_dir/*.*");
  sort($images);

  /*loop thought dir and get first Image*/
  if (count($images) > 0) {
  /*get product imagepath and set as src*/
  $tempclass->src = $images[0];

  /*return all data to array*/
  $this->Imagedata[] = clone($tempclass);
  }

}
```

My intention was to check my folder image and store first image to `Imagedata[]`, but I keep checking the `Imagedata[]` is empty, I don't know why. I checked the folderpath as well, it is correct so what  did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**After Question Edited:**

I think the best way to get files in a directory is :

```
$directory = "/domain/img/company/Image1-000000-016";
$images = scandir ($directory);
$firstImage = $directory . $files[2];


//$tempclass->src = $firstImage;
```

if this didn't work check directory permission and check if exists at all?

**Old Answer:**

You are doing just something small wrong! There is no $images variable at all! I think :

```
if (count($images) > 0) {
   $tempclass->src = $images[0];
   //....
}
```

Must be :

```
if (count($files) > 0) {
   $tempclass->src = $files[0];
   //....
}
```

Comment: sorry i mistype it , my file was $images but still i got empty array.

Comment: what happens if you var_dump($images) right after the glob?

Comment: array (size=0)
  empty
array (size=0)
  empty
array (size=0)
  empty
array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: isit my path problem?

Answer (score 0):

maybe because you store your files in `$files` variable and then check for `$images` variable which is undefined?

I really suggest you to spend some time into turning on E_NOTICE errors in your PHP environment, they help you a great deal in catching this kind of mistakes (it happens to everyone)

Comment: sorry i mistype it , my file was $images but still i got empty array.